# Using *this in C++ class method to fully overwrite self instantiation

Tags: c++, class, methods, this, instantiation

Is the following code safe? (I already know it compiles properly.)

```
void Tile::clear()
{
    *this = Tile();
}

int main()
{
    Tile mytile;

    mytile.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might work.  It depends on how `Tile& operator = (const Tile&);` is implemented.  However, there's nothing intrinsically erroneous with assigning `*this` to a new value.

Answer (score 1):

The code is OK, and [Herb Sutter even recommends](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/023.htm) calling the assignment operator on `this`, even within a constructor. I think that is an extremely clean, elegant solution. Even if it doesn't work at first, changing your code to make it work would probably be a matter of clean-up.

Comment: Then that's one thing where I disagree with Herb. Construction, even copy construction, and assignment are two different operations for a reason. If anything, the assignment operator should use the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), that is: it _does_ use the copy constructor, albeit in a better way than the one Herb's article started out with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on implementation. For example if the assignment operator relies on some member variable of class `Tile` being already initialized (and that is quite usual) and that variable is not initialized by the `Tile` constructor before you call the `*this =` assignment you program might run into undefined behavior.

Comment: How is this specific to the question? If a constructor doesn't properly initialize a member, doing _anything_ with the object might invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @sbi: Not anything. You could have an unused uninitialized pointer member variable. In this case you can safely instantiate and destroy the object. My point is that *it depends*.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't fly. Such a beast could also be assigned to and from.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, but UB will not be invoked until the assignment is invoked. If you for example create a temporary object and pass it by reference no UB happens. Again, my point is not that *it is good* or *it is bad*. My point is *it depends, show me the code*.

Answer (score -1):

Safe if your copy consturctor is not doing anything nasty.